# How can I calculate the right ratio

Tags: logarithms, calculator

I m currently preparing for sat subject mat 2 exam and whenever this type of question comes , answer that my calculator gives and the answer key says doesn't match.  Does anybody can help , maybe suggestions for a different approach ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC3rS.png)

I do the same thing in my calculator but get an answer 1.389975. I m using casio fx cg50
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQINg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take logs on both sides

$$\ln(8.1^a)=\ln(3.6^b)$$
Apply properties
$$a\ln(8.1)=b\ln(3.6)$$
$$\therefore \frac{a}{b}=\frac{\ln(3.6)}{\ln(8.1)}≈ 0.61$$

Thus the answer is B

Comment: Hmm , thank you.  I assume this dot between the numbers as a multiplication . so I was doing  log18/ log 8

Comment: @alpino No problem, if this has answered your question kindly accept the answer by clicking on the check mark

Comment: I m doing but it say you have to wait for 8 minutes , so it s on the countdown. I will do when it ends

Comment: @alpino I'm guessing you didn't learn math in the U.S.? Here, decimal numbers are shown with a point, as in $1.1 = \frac{11}{10} = 1 + \frac{1}{10}$. Multiplication is shown using a centered dot: $4\cdot 5 = 20$. Lastly, large numbers are shown with a comma, e.g. $1,000$ is one thousand, rather than $1.000$.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 You re right. Thanks for useful explanation for me